# Samba need an ip of same network of Windows Active Directory to make the join?

Tags: samba, kerberos, winbind

Im working to setup samba in windows network. The goal is windows users from Active Direcotry uses their passwords to log in samba shares.

I am not sure if, in this setup, AD server and Samba Server have to be in the same network? Is mandatory?

I have ping between both but are in a different networks.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're talking about using [ADS Security Mode](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/Samba-HOWTO-Collection/ServerType.html#id2560123) on your Samba server. These security modes permit Samba to offload authentication to the Active Directory (AD) domain.

The configuration process [is outlined in the Samba docs](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/Samba-HOWTO-Collection/domain-member.html#ads-member). Basically, you'll configure your Samba server with the name of the AD domain, configure the Kerberos `/etc/krb5.conf` file with details about the domain, and then join the domain (in a manner not unlike a domain member Windows computer).

It's unclear what you mean by "in the same network". Because the Samba server will forward authentication requests to a Domain Controller (DC), so it will be necessary for the Samba server to be able to communicate with one or more DCs. They don't have to be in the same IP subnet, but the Samba server will need reliable name resolution to be able to resolve the names of DCs.

Comment: Thanks Evan. Yes the goal is share samba folders to windows users, but leave the administration of users in windows active directory side. You have replied exactly what I was looking for, some guy told me that samba and AD have to be in the same subnet! Thanks for share your knowleadge.